# How critical is it and how to monitor, measure and reduce SharePoint database fragmentation?

Tags: database, 2007, maintenance

It is a well advertised best practice to configure maintenance plans for SQL databases forming the data layer of SharePoint deployments. How critical is it to monitor and reduce fragmentation of the databases and indices (indexes)? How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can follow up on your own answer with these articles from Kimberly Tripp:

[Database Maintenance Best Practices Part I – clarifying ambiguous recommendations for Sharepoint](http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/Database-Maintenance-Best-Practices-Part-I-e28093-clarifying-ambiguous-recommendations-for-Sharepoint.aspx)

[Database Maintenance Best Practices Part II – Setting FILLFACTOR](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/Database-Maintenance-Best-Practices-Part-II-e28093-the-most-important-setting-FILLFACTOR.aspx)

[Database Maintenance Best Practices Part III - Transaction Log Maintenance](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/Database-Maintenance-Best-Practices-Part-III-Transaction-Log-Maintenance.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There is a Microsoft whitepaper on the topic and a knowledge base article:  [Database maintenance for Office SharePoint Server 2007](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262731.aspx), [932774](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/932744/). Personal experience sharing will be appreciated.